# Segfault at initialization of simple for loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have to be losing my mind here. I'm getting a segfault at the line `for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {`. I've never encountered anything like this. Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 2400
#define M 2000
#define P 500

int main() {    
    int a[N][N];
    int b[N][N];
    int c[N][N];

    int i, j;

    // Initialize matrix A
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            a[i][j] = j-1+2;
        }
    }

    // Initialize matrix B
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < P; j++) {
            b[i][j] = i-j+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most compilers put local variables, including complete arrays, on the stack. The stack space is limited, on Windows the default stack-space is only a single megabyte. Your `a`, `b` and `c` arrays are 21MB, *each*.

Comment: ...so you should use `malloc()` or `calloc()` to allocate memory [on heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) for those arrays. Or just reduce elements count to fit into stack.

Comment: actually you're getting it at `int a[N][N];`

Comment: If you are under linux, run `ulimit -s unlimited` on the shell you are using the run the program executable in order to avoid running out of stack.

Comment: @simpel01 Alternatively, if you aren’t going to call `main()` recursively, declare the arrays `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First : you have declared a, b and c as [N][N] matrix, but you initialize them as if they were [N][M] and [M][P] matrix. Considering N > M > P, that should not cause a segfault, but the intent is not clear.

Second, if you replace your `defines` by :

```
#define N 10
#define M 5
#define P 2
```

Your program work. This is because local variables `a` and `b` are stored on the stack and your stack is limited in size. Consult your compiler and your system documentation to know exactly the limits imposed.

To avoid such problem, allocate your memory using `malloc` or equivalent function, that allocate memory on the heap, which is less constrained.